# How to upload screensot if the task is completed in django rest api

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Model

This is the model i created this model inside the Admin app

```
class AndroidApp(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    link = models.URLField()
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subcategory = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='app_images/')
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    points = models.IntegerField()
```

View

```
class UserAppDetailedView(APIView):

    def get(self,request,id):
        try:
            app = AndroidApp.objects.get(id=id)
        except AndroidApp.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'message': 'App not found.'}, status=404)

        serializer = AndroidAppSerializer(app)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def put(self, request, id):
        try:
            app = AndroidApp.objects.get(id=id)
        except AndroidApp.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'message': 'App not found.'}, status=404)

        if app.completed:
            return Response({'message': 'App already completed.'})

        app.completed = True
        app.save()
        serializer = AndroidAppSerializer(app)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def patch(self, request, id):
        app = AndroidApp.objects.get(id=id)
        if app:
            serializer = AndroidAppSerializer(app, data=request.data, partial=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                if app.completed:
                    screenshot = serializer.validated_data.get('screenshot', None)
                    if screenshot:
                        app.screenshot = screenshot
                        app.save()
                        return Response(serializer.data)
                    return Response({'message': 'Please provide a screenshot image.'}, status=400)
                else:
                    return Response({'message': 'App task is not completed.'}, status=400)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)
        return Response({'message': 'App not found.'}, status=404)
```

In tis code im trying to do first i check the app(task) is completed or not if the task is not completed the updated the task as true . it is working and after that i ant to upload the screen shot if the task is completed . so in my settings.py file i added media url. but it is not workin perfectly..